# Drop large set of tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there anyway to drop around 5 million table using single a SQL query or any other fast way?

1. View object explorer is not responding
2. `select top 1000 'drop table '+ name +';' from sys.tables where name like 'xxxx%'` takes 2 minutes
3. Looping and drop table also takes around 2 minutes

Comment: I would probably move rest of tables to another schema and drop that schema (if not dbo). Then rename new one to old name.

Comment: Thanks. Not possible as this is in a production environment.

Comment: Did you not provide a way to do this already? What's the real question--how to do it faster, or...?

Comment: execute drop statements without looping

Comment: Tried in 2. it also take around 2 min to 1000 tables

Comment: Define "fast"... is 5M = 5 million?

Comment: Yes it is 5 million table in a single database

Comment: it takes 2 mins because your are using LIKE 'xxxx%' ... LIKE is usually a performance killer

Comment: it is true but Not taking time to select query, but to drop table

Comment: 5 million tables??? That sounds like the worst data model ever. I cannot imagine a database dealing with 5 million *different* entities. Are you in the process of fixing that? One or few tables with millions of rows instead of millions of tables?

Comment: Agreed @ThorstenKettner it sounds like it'd be quicker to copy the tables they need and drop the entire database.

Comment: It was due to an error , we have fixed it but unable to drop tables

Comment: There is no way you are going to drop 5 million tables quickly. It is going to take quite a bit of time. I would suggest doing this in batches to let other processes continue to function while you clean this nightmare up.

Comment: Why does it even matter if it was just by mistake and you're just clearing it? Are you planning to make the same mistake over and over again... :)

Comment: Move the tables you want to keep, then drop the whole database?

Comment: If this is a one time job, are you not spending more time looking for alternatives than it would take by brute force?

Comment: Does changing to Simple Recovery Mode speed it up?

Comment: i also think change recovery mode will help. but unable to do now as this is a production,if there is no other option this would be the last option

Comment: I had to double check that SQL Server actually allows that many tables. [Yes, it does, the limit is 2 GiB worth of objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server). Here's one situation where a generous limit isn't actually helping. And you can't really expect `DROP TABLE` to be an operation that's high on the list of statements to optimize for performance...

Answer (score 3):

So the two approaches you've tested, which are quite different, each take 2 minutes to process 1000 tables.  This strongly suggests that the time is being consumed by the actual act of dropping the tables, not by the method of specifying what to drop.  In other words, there probably *is* no clever way to do it faster, if you can't migrate to a new database and drop this one.

In fairness, that's less than 1/8sec per drop.  In computer time, 1/8sec is a long time I guess; but a fair amount has to be done to drop a table while maintaining the integrity of the DBMS, and presumably while other things are going on.  So it doesn't seem outrageous that this might simply be the pace at which the work can be done.

5,000,000 tables at 500 tables per minute is just under 1 week.  IMO you might as well let that process get started, and now you know how long you have to think of something better :)

Answer (score 2):

Without looping (SQL Server 2017+):

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = (select 'DROP TABLE ' + string_agg(name,',')  
                              from sys.tables where name like 'xxxx%');
PRINT @sql;  -- debug only
EXEC(@sql);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3ec09da0fa621845bb908fb18197046e)**

Comment: Thanks. Expecting something to do with using sys.objects or sys.tables